# Why Object.prototype looks like a empty object?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(Object.prototype); // -> "{}"
```

I expected console.log(Object.prototype) to output some properties or mothods like "toString".
Why it doesn't?

Comment: Why would you expect methods in there like `toString()`?

Comment: Because the Object has toString() method and I can call it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default methods are not marked as enumerable and thus not shown when viewing `Object.prototype`.

The reason for this is pretty simple: When viewing some object or more important iterating over its properties using `for(var prop in object)` you usually do not want to see any of the default methods. Of course one could always use a `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` check in such a loop but it's incredibly comfortable not having to do this by knowing that there's nothing enumerable on `Object.prototype` by default (and good code doesn't add enumerable properties to it either).

Comment: What is marking as enurable ? It makes me think, why aren't array methods iterated over when you use for var in ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute